# how to scp across servers using bash?

Tags: bash, scp

Is it doable?

Answer (score 4):

Well, yes, it is. How about this?

```
scp pax@machine1:/tmp/qq pax@machine2:/tmp/qq
```

Either that's it, or I'm missing something fundamental in your question.

See:

```
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
       [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Comment: Password is needed at least I think..

Comment: It uses the same methods as ssh (which in my case allows for pageant, the putty agent). See "man ssh" for non_windows methods including the use of /etc/[s]hosts.equiv and ~/.[rs]hosts.

Comment: @shore: It will prompt you for a password.

Comment: @Dennis, you're right but it checks the other methods first, If you have SSH trust set up between the two machines or an SSH key set up, it shouldn't prompt you.